# Open a date picker by clicking on checkbox and set new date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using  [bootstrap-datepicker-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails) there's one problem I can't solve.
I have following structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-element" data-provide='datepicker' value="<%= Time.now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') %>" >
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="date-checkbox" value="">Set different date</label>
```

What I need to accomplish is to make it possible to open datepicker and set new date (as you see, its default value is current date).
I tried following:

```
$('.date-checkbox').click(function() {
    $('.datepicker-element').datepicker();
});
```

but it doesn't work as well as `onChange` event and calling `.datepicker()` on checkbox. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html#show

Comment: Dang, that's what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using gem's standard methods described in its documentation you can find by the [link](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/methods.html#show).
So my solution looks like this:

```
$('.date-checkbox').click(function() {
    $('.datepicker-element').datepicker('show');
});
```